# FormCalc - Round function - remove trailing zeros

Tags: decimal, rounding, zero, livecycle-designer

I am using LiveCycle to program a calculator.  I have some float calulations which I have concated into the string as below.

```
var n1 = Round(123/33,1)
var n2 = Round(100/25.003)
textbox1 = ConCat("between " n1 " and " n2)
```

n1 will display as 3.7 and n2 will display as 4.0 but with other calculations it will display as a whole number with no trailing decimals.

I want to remove the trailing zeros where applicable.  I have a number of these calculations and it just seems random which ones remove trailing zeros and which ones are kept.

Help would be appreciated if there is a different, more elegant approach

Thanks

Comment: Your sample works fine for me when I correct the syntax by using commas in the Concat() function:
var n1 = Round(123/33,1)
var n2 = Round(100/25.003)
Concat("between ", n1, " and ", n2)

results in:
between 3.7 and 4

I'm using AEM Designer 6.1 - what version of Designer are you using?

Comment: Sorry I didn't give the actual numbers I was working with so may have worked nicely - for using the round function appears to require explicit format statement. Using lifecycle designer Es 2 and the answer below worked- thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
var n1 = Round(123/33,1)
var n2 = Round(100/25.003)
Concat("between ", Format("zzz9.z", n1), " and ", Format("zzz9.z", n2))
```

While not as elegant/succinct as letting the FormCalc engine perform the string conversion for you, it should be more reliable because it's explicit.